# Sampling subset to span entire range of full set (*not* to be representative), in order to construct some sort of lookup table

Tags: sampling, python, interpolation

I have a large number of $N$ (20770) measurements.
I need to perfom a calculation on all of them, but this is computationally too expensive.
Therefore, I am looking for a way to select a subset of $p$ (~300) measurements.
Then, I can use any of those $N$ measurements, look which one of the subset $p$ is closest, and use the calculation for this reference measurement; like a lookup-table.
The aim of the subset is thus *not* to be representative of the full set, but to span the entire range in each relevant dimension.

I can think of several ways to establish this subset (such as using EOFs to maximise variability, or something along the lines of [Chevallier et al. (2006)](https://nwpsaf.eu/downloads/profiles/profiles_91L.pdf) but the latter lacks algorithm details), but I don't want to spend months on this, as it is not essential that it is done in the best possible way; a simpler but sub-optimal way is highly preferrable.
A simple way I can think of is to bucket my measurements based on $d$ dimensions (say $d=6$).
Then, I can lookup which reference measurement fits in the same $d$-dimensional bucket as the current measurement, and use the calculation for that reference measurement.

My fear is that I am reinventing the wheel and spending time on developing a poor homegrown solution to a problem that has well-established solutions along with implementation in popular languages.  That brings me to my question:

Is the problem described above one encountered commonly enough so that there exists: (1) a name and literature on alternative solutions, and (2) open-source implementations of those solutions in popular packages, in particular for Python?

Comment: You will be, as they say, cursed by the dimensionality. In six dimensions you can cut each dimension into fewer than three classes on average (because even $3^6 \gt 300$)--and, of course, with effectively just one class for any additional dimensions. For most applications this will be too crude. Your only hope is that the data follow a multivariate functional form that has a very parsimonious description. Is there any possibility of that?

Comment: What if, in my database, almost all classes are empty?  I have 20770 elements, and with my bucketing I have 5760000 classes.  304 classes are non-empty, with at least 1 and at most 840 measurements in a class.  (Almost) all subsequent measurements will fall in those 304 classes or ones that are very close.  So my class database is actually very sparse.  I'm not sure what a "parsimonious description" means.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if interpolation is even necessary — if the class in which a measurement fits corresponds to the class for which I have a reference measurement (and it should, because that's how I constructed the references), I would simply take that reference as such (I guess that would effectively be nearest-neighbour with distances defined by the bucketing).

Comment: And that indeed is a (crude) form of interpolation. Unless I have grossly misunderstood your purpose--which is to use a small set of well-distributed values in order to predict all the other values--then your question is definitely about interpolation. It is interesting in that you have the opportunity to *design* the interpolating function (rather than merely interpolating given data). A "parsimonious description" is one that is not as complex as specifying 300 7-tuples (six coordinates and one value for each), such as a function that incorporates (say) only 20 parameters.

Comment: @whuber I get it.  My question is indeed about interpolation, then.  My confusion was that I don't need some parameterisation fit to the data (which is what I usually do when interpolating).